# Python regular expression returns nothing for match

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup

I am learning web scraping using Python. I am trying to extract all links from one of popular financial site's site map.

```
bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

for link in bsObj.findAll("a", 
href=re.compile("^(/india/stockmarket/pricechartquote/)*$")):

    if 'href' in link.attrs:
        print(link.attrs['href'])
print('found nothing')
```

This code founds nothing. Although many links with above match is present in site.
Sample : /india/stockmarket/pricechartquote/A

Comment: is `href=...` line properly indented?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried checking if this regex matches the provided part of a url - it does not:

```
>>> import re
>>>
>>> pattern = re.compile("^(/india/stockmarket/pricechartquote/)*$")
>>> pattern.search("/india/stockmarket/pricechartquote/A")
>>>
```

Instead, you meant to have the last part after the `pricechartquote/` matching, for instance, one or more uppercase letters:

```
>>> pattern = re.compile(r"^/india/stockmarket/pricechartquote/[A-Z]+$")
>>> pattern.search("/india/stockmarket/pricechartquote/A")
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x109240098>
```

Please adjust the `[A-Z]+` part depending on what kind of character set you expect to see after `pricechartquote/`.

---

Also note that you don't have to check the beginning and end of the string and might be good to go with a partial url match:

```
for link in bsObj.find_all("a", href=re.compile(r"/india/stockmarket/pricechartquote/")):
    # ...
```

Comment: what if I want to find wild characters after /pricechartquote/ ? Can't I use something like : '^(/india/stockmarket/pricechartquote/*)$' ?

Comment: @BhaveshGhodasara you can just do `/india/stockmarket/pricechartquote/.*` or if you want that wildcard not to match `/`, you can do smth like `/india/stockmarket/pricechartquote/[^/]+`.

Comment: @alexce why /india/stockmarket/pricechartquote/.* will work and why /india/stockmarket/pricechartquote/* will not work?

Comment: @BhaveshGhodasara cause `*` has a special meaning, it is a quantifier. When you write `.*` you are matching any characters any number of times in a greedy fashion.